# how to use auto-release in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, autorelease

I want to use the auto-release in my apps. I want to implement this methods 
[image: get by analyze]

```
- (void)selectorConnect: (NSArray *)args
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    //some code 

    [pool release];
}
```

Getting crash at `[pool release]` line. Any solution for that .

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but why not ARC?

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: seems not able to upgrade my whole application in ARC so we have to go with this method only.so ,any solution of above method?

Comment: you can enable ARC on individual files - just pass the linker flag `-fobjc-arc` in the build phase for that file.

Comment: Also, i see two `[pool release]`. Where is it crashing? first or second one? in your line `//some code`, what is the code in there?

Comment: @PhillipMills libobjc.A.dylib 0x349a45aa objc_msgSend + 9 get this type of crash when above method call.

Comment: Please show **all** of the crash information, including the exception from the console.  (If you don't see that, set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions.)  All one line from the stack tells us is that you have an error when a message is sent to some object...which probably doesn't solve your problem.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you empty an autorelease pool, it calls `autorelease` on all objects inside it.

If you're getting a crash with the `[pool release]` line then you've added an object to the autorelease pool and have released it yourself.

Run the static analyser and see what warnings it gives you.

And if you still don't know, enable `NSZombies` and see what object is being released twice.

Finally, if that still doesn't help, add your code to the question and we can all take a look :)

Comment: That tells me you need to autorelease both `args` and `socketControl` - they are being inited by you but not released. However, they aren't the reason that your pool is crashing. I assumed that it was the second call to `[pool release]` in your question that was causing the crash?

Comment: @deanWombourne: no, `_socketControl` is an instance variable and is correctly retained. The analyzer is pointing to the leak of the `NSNumber` object

Comment: @newacct - Oops, you're absolutely right :) Sorry, I answered too quickly, shame on me!